# See logcat results through wifi?

Tags: android

I would like to know is it possible to see logcat results on my system/laptop ; when i run my app in case i dont have a datacable to connect my device.Probably through Wifi.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can enable this as described [in this tutorial](http://stuffandtech.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html).

There are also a bunch of Apps that should be capable of this, for example [ADB WiFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw).

Answer (score 1):

Android 11+ has a native support to adb over Wi-Fi: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+